# Is stochastic process completely non-deterministic (specific example)

Tags: statistics, stochastic-processes

Let $X(n)_{n\in \mathbb Z}$ be a centered stochastic process with covariance function $b(n)=\vert a\vert ^n$.

Define the following closed linear subspace of $L^2$:

$$H_X(t) =: \overline{\left\{\sum_{k \in K} c_k X(k), K \subset (-\infty,t],K\text{ finite}\right\}}$$

as well as

$$H_X(-\infty) = \cap_{t\in \mathbb Z} H_X(t)$$

Now, if $H_X(-\infty) = \{0\}$, then $X$ is called completely non-deterministic.

**Question**:Based on the information about the covariance function of $X$ only, can one say whether or not $X$ is completely non-deterministic?

My problem is that I don't know how to get from this "Hilbert space language" to treating a specific process. The only theorem I have in mind is the following:

**Theorem**: A weakly stationary sequence $X(t)$ is completely non-deterministic if and only if there exist a sequence of uncorrelated random variables $W(n)$, such that

$$X(t) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n W(t-n), \qquad \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \vert a_n \vert ^2 < \infty, \qquad \mathbb E[\vert W_0 \vert^2]=1,$$

but I don't see how this criterion helps me answer this question since there is no reference to the covariance function.

Comment: Suggestions: define "completely non-deterministic"; add your thoughts.

Comment: I edited my question, thanks for help!

Comment: Thanks for the explanations. See answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $b_n=\alpha^n$, then $E[X(t)^2]=1$ and the random variables $W(t)=X(t)-\alpha X(t-1)$ are uncorrelated and $X(t)=\sum\limits_{n\geqslant0}a_nW(t-n)$ with $a_n=\alpha^n$. For every $|\alpha|\lt1$, $\sum\limits_{n\geqslant0}|a_n|^2$ is finite.